# Rails - Make model without database taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a tableless model like this:

```
class Wiki 
    include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    # No Database
    def persisted?
        false
    end
    # ...
end
```

When I claim `acts_as_taggable` in this model, I got `undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_taggable'` for it. However I tried include `ActiveModel::Model`, it still doesn't work. Any ideas I can make my tableless model be taggable?

Comment: Are you using `acts_as_taggable` gem or some other gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [source code of the plugin](https://github.com/ivoreis/acts_as_taggable/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable.rb#L47-L50), it requires that you use it with AR. It includes itself into `ActiveRecord::Base`.

So, you may want to add those into your class as well, like so:

```
class Wiki 
    include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    # Adding `acts_as_taggable`
    extend ActsAsTaggable::Taggable
    include ActsAsTaggable::Tagger

    # No Database
    def persisted?
        false
    end
    # ...
end
```

---

#### But!

But, then again, you will have to include more AR modules to make it work. Since, the gem requires that your class AR specific methods that are available in `ActiveRecord::Base` class, such as `has_many`, etc.

For [example here](https://github.com/ivoreis/acts_as_taggable/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable/taggable.rb#L85):

```
has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy, :include => :tag, :class_name => "ActsAsTaggable::Extra::Tagging"
has_many :base_tags, :through => :taggings, :source => :tag, :class_name => "ActsAsTaggable::Tag"
```